# Python object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, glade

I've got a strange problem.
I've got a test script where it works. Now i have used the same code i my main script and now it's not working and i can't se why not.
So i hope someone can see what went wrong.

When i run the script i throws an error:

```
File "E:/Python/Amp_Glade_1.py", line 226, in
  on_volume_scale_value_changed
    self.update_control("volume", x)
File "E:/Python/Amp_Glade_1.py", line 264, in update_control
    self.control[self.name] = self.value
AttributeError: 'GTK_Main' object has no attribute 'control'
```

So in:

```
def on_volume_scale_value_changed(self, object, data=None):
    x = int(self.volume.get_value())
    y = self.volume_step[x]
    self.label_volume.set_text(str(y))
    self.update_control("volume", x)
```

I call:

```
def update_control(self, name, value):
    self.name = name
    self.value = value
    self.control[self.name] = self.value
```

And i can't see what will cause that error, as it is working in my test script. 
This is the dict that is self.control:

```
self.control = {"volume": 3, "bass": 0,
                    "middle": 0, "treble": 0,
                    "center": 16, "pre_gain": 0}
```

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
GUI / Amlifier control
Connects to ESP8266 on wifi
Controls Pre-Amp and Amplifier
```

'''

```
try:
    import os
 except:
    print ("No os")

try:
    import thread
 except:
print ("No thread")

try:
    import gi
except:
    print ("No gi")

try:
    import sys
except:
    print ("No sys")

try:
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
    from gi.repository import GObject, Gtk as Gtk
except:
    print ("No Gtk")

try:
    import socket
except:
    print ("No socket")

try:
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
except:
    print ("No datetime, timedelta")

try:
    # neede for window.get_xid(), xvimagesink.set_window_handle(),     respectively:
    gi.require_version('GdkX11', '3.0')
    from gi.repository import GdkX11
except:
    print ("No GdkX11")
    sys.exit()


class GTK_Main(object):

    def __init__(self, sock=None):

        ## Create window
        self.gladefile  = ("Amp_2.glade")
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        ## Create objects by name frpm gladefile
        self.window = self.builder.get_object("window")
        self.Store = self.builder.get_object("Store")
        self.Mute = self.builder.get_object("Mute")
        self.Load = self.builder.get_object("Load")
        self.Reset = self.builder.get_object("Reset")
        self.bass = self.builder.get_object("bass_scale")
        self.middle = self.builder.get_object("middle_scale")
        self.treble = self.builder.get_object("treble_scale")
        self.volume = self.builder.get_object("volume_scale")
        self.pre_gain = self.builder.get_object("gain")
        self.center = self.builder.get_object("center_scale")
        self.label_bass = self.builder.get_object("label_bass")
        self.label_middle = self.builder.get_object("label_middle")
        self.label_treble = self.builder.get_object("label_treble")
        self.label_volume = self.builder.get_object("label_volume")
        self.label_pre_gain = self.builder.get_object("label_gain")
        self.label_center = self.builder.get_object("label_center")
        self.label_IP = self.builder.get_object("label_IP")
        self.label_Port = self.builder.get_object("label_Port")
        self.label_connected = self.builder.get_object("label_connected")
        self.image_mute = self.builder.get_object("image1")
        self.image_radio_1 = self.builder.get_object("image2")
        self.image_radio_2 = self.builder.get_object("image3")
        self.image_radio_3 = self.builder.get_object("image4")
        self.image_radio_4 = self.builder.get_object("image5")
        self.radiobutten_1 = self.builder.get_object("radiobutton1")
        self.radiobutten_2 = self.builder.get_object("radiobutton2")
        self.radiobutten_3 = self.builder.get_object("radiobutton3")
        self.radiobutten_4 = self.builder.get_object("radiobutton4")

        self.window.show_all()

        ## Set init values
        self.mute_state = False
        self.center.set_value(16)

        self.host = '192.168.0.23'
        self.port = 8888

        ## Create TCP socket
        if sock is None:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                                  socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        else:
            self.sock = sock

        self.connect(self.host, self.port)

        ## Scale steps
        self.volume_step = (-40, -32. -24, -16, -8, -7,
                        -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0)

        self.pre_gain_step = (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,
                          16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30)

        self.bass_step = (-14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0,
                      2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14)

        self.middle_step = (-14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0,
                      2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14)

        self.treble = (-14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0,
                      2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14)

        self.right_step = (0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6,
                       -7, -8, -16, -24, -32,
                       -40, -48, -56, -64, -72)

        self.left_step = (0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6,
                       -7, -8, -16, -24, -32,
                       -40, -48, -56, -64, -72)

        ## Set init scale values
        self.volume.set_value(3)

        ## JSON
        self.control = {"volume": 3, "bass": 0,
                    "middle": 0, "treble": 0,
                    "center": 16, "pre_gain": 0}

        ## Graphic elements to control
        self.GUI_labels = {"volume": self.label_volume,
                       "bass": self.label_bass,
                       "middle": self.label_middle,
                       "treble": self.label_treble,
                       "center": self.label_center,
                       "pre_gain": self.label_pre_gain}

        self.GUI_items = {"volume": self.volume, "bass": self.bass,
                      "middle": self.middle, "treble": self.treble,
                      "center": self.center, "pre_gain": self.pre_gain}

        ## start ping to server
        thread.start_new_thread(self.ping_send(), )

        ## Create handles
    def on_window_destroy(self, obkect, data=None):
        self.sock.close()
        thread.exit()
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def connect(self, host, port):
        try:
            self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
            self.label_connected.set_text("Connection:")
            self.label_IP.set_text(self.host)
            self.label_Port.set_text(str(self.port))
        except Exception as e:
            print("No connection. Exceptions is %s:" % (e))
            self.label_connected.set_text("No connection")

        return None

    def on_Mute_released(self, object, data=None):
        if not self.mute_state:
            self.image_mute.set_from_file("circle_red_small.png")
            self.mute_state = True
        else:
            self.image_mute.set_from_file("circle_blue_small.png")
            self.mute_state = False

    def on_radiobutton1_pressed(self, object, data=None):
        self.image_radio_1.set_from_file("circle_green_small.png")
        self.image_radio_2.set_from_file("circle_blue_small.png")
        self.image_radio_3.set_from_file("circle_blue_small.png")
        self.image_radio_4.set_from_file("circle_blue_small.png")

    def on_radiobutton2_pressed(self, object, data=None):
        self.image_radio_2.set_from_file("circle_green_small.png")
        self.image_radio_1.set_from_file("circle_blue_small.png")
        self.image_radio_3.set_from_file("circle_blue_small.png")
        self.image_radio_4.set_from_file("circle_blue_small.png")

    def on_radiobutton3_pressed(self, object, data=None):
        self.image_radio_3.set_from_file("circle_green_small.png")
        self.image_radio_1.set_from_file("circle_blue_small.png")
        self.image_radio_2.set_from_file("circle_blue_small.png")
        self.image_radio_4.set_from_file("circle_blue_small.png")

    def on_radiobutton4_pressed(self, object, data=None):
        self.image_radio_4.set_from_file("circle_green_small.png")
        self.image_radio_1.set_from_file("circle_blue_small.png")
        self.image_radio_2.set_from_file("circle_blue_small.png")
        self.image_radio_3.set_from_file("circle_blue_small.png")

    def on_Reset_released(self, object, data=None):
        pass

    def on_Store_released(self, object, data=None):
        pass

    def on_Load_released(self, object, data=None):
        pass

    def on_center_scale_value_changed(self, object, data=None):
        pass

    def on_volume_scale_value_changed(self, object, data=None):
        x = int(self.volume.get_value())
        y = self.volume_step[x]
        self.label_volume.set_text(str(y))
        self.update_control("volume", x)

    def on_bass_scale_value_changed(self, object, data=None):
        pass

    def on_middle_scale_value_changed(self, object, data=None):
        pass

    def on_treble_scale_value_changed(self, object, data=None):
        pass

    def on_gain_scale_value_changed(self, object, data=None):
        pass

    def ping_send(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        next_ping= now + timedelta(hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 5)
        while True:
            if next_ping <= datetime.now():
                self.mysend("OK")
                now = next_ping
                next_ping = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours = 0, minutes     = 0,
                                               seconds = 5)
            while Gtk.events_pending():
                Gtk.main_iteration()

    def mysend(self, msg):
        totalsent = 0
        MSGLEN = len(msg)
        while totalsent < MSGLEN:
            sent = self.sock.send(msg[totalsent:])
            if sent == 0:
                raise RuntimeError("Socket connection broken")
            totalsent = totalsent + sent

    def update_control(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.control[self.name] = self.value

    def write_json(self):
        with open("amp.dat", "w+") as jsonFile:
            jsonFile.write(json.dumps(self.control))
            jsonFile.close()

    def load_json(self):
        with open("amp.dat", "r") as jsonFile:
            data = json.load(jsonFile)
            jsonFile.close()
            self.control = json.dumps(data)

    def update_GUI(self):
        for key in self.control.items():
            if key == "gain":
                pass
            else:
                x = self.GUI_labels[key]
                x.set_text(str(value))
                y = self.GUI_items[key]
                y.set_value(value)


GObject.threads_init()
GTK_Main() 
Gtk.main()
```

So mayby someone can tell whats wrong?
I would really appreciate it.

Comment: [mcve] please. The code you posted isn't formatted correctly, and nowhere near *minimal*.

Comment: And since we don't have your glade file, the code you posted isn't *complete* either.

Comment: @Aran-Frey  And for need do you have for the Gladefile?
Yes  there could be posted less, but now it is the all. I have pointed out the essential functions.
So if you don't now the answer, please go just go on.

Comment: The point of asking for a minimal and complete example is two-fold. 1) If it is complete then others can actually reproduce (otherwise it might be a guess). 2) The process of creating a minimal example (slowly removing parts of you script till you have just enough to demonstrate the error) can often make it obvious what is the error so that you can answer yourself what went wrong.

Comment: @SethMMorton Yes it all fine.
But if you have read my desription of the problem, you wouls have noticed, that i've got a testscript where it works.
So please forgive me for putting up the hole script where is not working.
I you want the glade file, fine i'll give it to you.
But as far i can see, it has nothing to do with the gladefile. Only the Python code, Especially: Why is self.control suddently not recognized?

Comment: But you did not show the test script that works, so we cannot compare the two to try and help. Remember, folks on this site are only helping you in their spare time on a voluntary basis. If you make it harder to help by not providing enough relevant information while at the same time posting a wall of code that probably has a lot of irrelevant information you will be less likely to get help because it is more work for the volunteers.

Comment: You're right, it has nothing to do with the glade file. You should remove that part of the code and thus create a *minimal*, *complete*, and *verifiable* example.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with this code. I will first state what I *think* is the problem and how to solve that, but then move on to other issues.

---

There is a lot of non-obvious stuff going on here, and I imagine it is because the GTK framework is doing some things implicitly. For example, I note that `GTK_Main` is instantiated but the resulting object is never saved anywhere. My guess is that there is some sort of weird nested dependency that occurs when you do

```py
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        ...
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)
```

and that somehow the this allows the instantiated object to connect with the GTK event loop.

I also suspect that somehow the `builder` expects that this object implement methods like `on_volume_scale_value_changed` that are to be executed when the volume scale value changes.

If this is true, then the following code causes the error

```py
        ## Set init scale values
        self.volume.set_value(3)

        ## JSON
        self.control = {"volume": 3, "bass": 0,
                    "middle": 0, "treble": 0,
                    "center": 16, "pre_gain": 0}
```

This would be because setting the volume would trigger the `on_volume_scale_value_changed` to be called, which attempts to access `self.control`, but you do not define `self.control` till *after* the volume is set.  Reversing the order *should* fix the problem.

In general, you should

1. *always* set data members (like `self.control`, since it just holds data) before performing any logic (like setting the volume), and
2. Be aware of the order things are called so you don't get into loops like this.

---

Having said that, the next problem you will have is here:

```py
    def load_json(self):
        with open("amp.dat", "r") as jsonFile:
            data = json.load(jsonFile)
            jsonFile.close()
            self.control = json.dumps(data)
```

`self.control` should be a dictionary, yet you are setting it to the output of `json.dumps` which will be a string. So if you ever call that function your code will stop working. You should just do `self.control = json.load(jsonFile)`.

Additionally, in a context manager (the `with` block) a file is automatically closed upon exit, so calling `jsonFile.close()` explicitly is redundant at best - at worst it might raise an error when exiting the `with` block because the file is already closed.

---

All of the

```py
try:
    import sys
 except:
    print ("No sys")
```

is very bad for the following reasons

1. You are doing a blanket `except`, rather than catching a specific error. I am assuming you are trying to catch `ImportError`, so you should do `except ImportError`. You have know idea what other types of exceptions could be raised, so you don't know what could be swallowed and leave your system in an invalid state. Which brings me to
2. You are trying to import a module, but if that fails you are just printing that it doesn't exist and moving on. In the case of `os` and `sys` that's fine since you never use `os` (though I would say you should avoid importing things you do not use) and `sys` is only used for `sys.exit()` (which would trigger an exit anyway since `sys` is missing), but what if `datetime` couldn't be imported? You use `datetime` in your code, so your code might run for who knows how long then suddenly fail when you try to use `datetime`. In general it is MUCH better to fail early and descriptively rather than leave your system in a broken state which could fail at any time.
3. Most of the imports you are doing this with are from the standard library. If something from the standard library is missing then there is a problem. Especially `sys`... I don't think python can start without `sys`.
4. If a module does not exist, it will raise an `ImportError` and tell the user it does not exist, then halt code. This is what you want, since if GTK were missing you couldn't run your code anyway.

Moral: NEVER swallow errors and keep on going, because it leaves your system in a broken state where things can fail at any time for no apparent reason.

Comment: 1: self.builder = Gtk.Builder is the Gtk.builder instantiated as self.builder, so it is saved. 
self.builder.connect_signals(self) is builder that connects to the object signals, that is in the Gladefile and is a part of object now,as self.builder has loaded the Gladefile. That how it works with a Glade file.

2: Yes the try:  import could be more elegant. It's only there as a old habit from a time where my python2.7 didn't necessarily have all the modules installed.
It's just a notifyer for me self. os is importet only if i needed at some point.

Comment: 3: There seems be no trouble with closing a jsonfile. The data from the file is already stored in data. As long that function is in use the data from jsonfile will be held in variabel "data".

Comment: 4: Just done a test where def update_control: is move up in the script before, the function get called 1. time and there is no difference,
As functions have been coded, they also have produced errors at startup.
But all of these function is working as they should. When they are in use, they don't create any errors.
So at the end of the day, i will swallow those errors as no one seems to be able to give an explaination on why they suddently appears, when they don't do it in the test script, where i test functions.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is just a typo `onkect` here, and not in the actual code?

```
 def on_window_destroy(self, obkect, data=None):
         self.sock.close()
         thread.exit()
         Gtk.main_quit()
```

Comment: Yes is a typo, but is not the cause for my problem. If it only had... :-)

Answer (score 0):

It must be a some kind of bug in the compiler.
After done a hole lot of testing, commented out several regions, made new variables
it stills create an error on start up.
But how ever, the function works as expected.